# Error: No overload matches this call. Overload 1 of 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm getting the following typescript(ts2769) error in angular 12.1.1

**Error:**

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(start: number, deleteCount?: number | undefined): Todo[] | undefined', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(start: number, deleteCount: number, ...items: Todo[]): Todo[] | undefined', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

**For the following code:**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { of } from 'rxjs';

import {Todo} from "./../model/Todo"

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TodoService {
  todos: Todo[] | undefined;

  constructor() {
    this.todos = [
      {
        id: '111',
        title: "Learn C++",
        isCompleted: true,
        date: new Date(),
      },{
        id: '222',
        title: "Learn React",
        isCompleted: true,
        date: new Date(),
      },
      {
        id: '333',
        title: "Learn Angular",
        isCompleted: false,
        date: new Date(),
      },
    ];
   }


   getTodos(){
     return of(this.todos)
   }
  
   addTodo(todo: Todo) {
     this.todos?.push(todo)
   }

   changeStatus(todo: Todo){
    this.todos?.map( singleTodo => {
      if (singleTodo.id == todo.id) {
        todo.isCompleted = !todo.isCompleted;
      }
    } );
   }

   deleteTodo(todo: Todo){
     const indexofTodo  = this.todos?.findIndex(
       (currentObj) => currentObj.id === todo.id
     ) ;
     this.todos?.splice(indexofTodo, 1);  //Error showing here for indexofTodo
   }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

`indexofTodo` has type `number | undefined` because `this.todos?.findIndex` can return a number or `undefined` (if `this.todos` is `undefined`). But you can't call `splice` with `undefined`. You can fix it with a type check:

```
if (indexofTodo !== undefined) this.todos?.splice(indexofTodo, 1);
```

or you can replace

```
todos: Todo[] | undefined;
```

With

```
todos: Todo[];
```

it means the same.

Comment: Yes it's solved, by replacing it with the following    todos: Todo[ ] ;   Thanks:)